# phpexcel excel data insert issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpexcel

I have an excel file which includes 15 column and 248 rows. I want to insert this excel file data into database. For this purpose i choose PHPExcel script. With this script i have successfully inserted 14 column data into database table. But 15 column name 'Description' included on html tags or codes in each cell. When i try to upload it along others 14 column then only 92 records inserted instead 248. Without 15 column others successfully insert 248 rows.  I am sharing my codes my let me know where is problem. Thanks

```
>include($HTTP_SERVER_VARS["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/my_session.php");<br>
>require_once($HTTP_SERVER_VARS["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/includes/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");

>$filetype = $_FILES["file"]["type"];<br>
$filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];<br>
$filetmp = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];<br>
$Ext = strrchr($filename,".");<br>
//set_time_limit(3000);

>$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_CSV();<br>
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("ebay.csv");<br>

>foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {<br>
    $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();<br>
    $highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); <br>
    $highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); <br>
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);<br>
    $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64; <br>
>for ($row=2; $row<=$highestRow; $row++) {<br>
        $item_name = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getValue();<br>
        $condition = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $row)->getValue();<br>
        $Category = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7, $row)->getValue();<br>
        $Quantity = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(11, $row)->getValue();<br>
        $StartPrice = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(14, $row)->getValue();<br>
        $BuyItNowPrice = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(15, $row)->getValue();<br>
        $Duration = "365";<br>
        $ItemID = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(29, $row)->getValue();<br>
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->getValue();<br>
        $PostageServices1 = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(95, $row)->getValue();<br>
        $PostageCost1 = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(96, $row)->getValue();<br>
        $PostageServices2 = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(101, $row)->getValue();<br>
        $PostageCost2 = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(102, $row)->getValue();<br>
        $PostageServices3 = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(106, $row)->getValue();<br>
        $PostageCost3 = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(107, $row)->getValue();<br>
        $DispatchTimeMax = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(122, $row)->getValue();<br>
        $ReturnsAcceptedOption = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(195, $row)->getValue();<br>
        $AdditionalDetails = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(202, $row)->getValue();<br>
        $item_description = stripslashes($worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(30, $row)->getValue());<br>

>insertInto("INSERT INTO mytable (`item_name`,`condition`,`Category`,`Quantity`,`StartPrice`,`BuyItNowPrice`,`Duration`,`item_code`,`PostageServices1`,`PostageCost1`,`PostageServices2`,`PostageCost2`,`PostageServices3`,`PostageCost3`,`DispatchTimeMax`,`ReturnsAcceptedOption`,`AdditionalDetails`) VALUES ('$item_name','$condition','$Category','$Quantity','$StartPrice','$BuyItNowPrice','$Duration','$ItemID','$PostageServices1','$PostageCost1','$PostageServices2','$PostageCost2','$PostageServices3','$PostageCost3','$DispatchTimeMax','$ReturnsAcceptedOption','$AdditionalDetails')");
}
}<br>
```

The description cell contains on html elements i.e table, p, b font so on... Each excel cell is heavy therefore i need proper method which will deal with html. Is there any function or method in phpexcel that will handle this html cell data and take it from excel and insert into database from start to end? If yes please give me at least one example.

Comment: What is the actual problem? If the content of the cell is straight text (it doesn't matter whether that text comprises html markup or not), it's still a text string. What do you expect to get from excel, and insert into the database? It would be different if it was rich text!!

Comment: Are you certain that the Description column is HTML markup and not rich text?

Comment: I want to insert total rows (248) into database but in the above mentioned codes stop inserting after first 92. I tested all column one by one all are inserting complete rows into database. But when i include description column other columns also stop inserting after first 92 rows. And when i tried to insert single description column from excel to db the problem was same (92). The description column in excel file contains html source in each cell. Can you tell how this description column execute all rows on insertion time? Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: "<table cellspacing=""28"" cellpadding=""0"" width=""100%"">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign=""top"">
<p align=""center""><font size=""5""></font>&nbsp;</p>
<p align=""center""><span class=""Apple-style-span"" style=""font-size: x-large;"">Clover / Shamrock Table Runner</span></p>
<p align=""center""><font size=""5"">40cm wide x 180cm long&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; 16"" x 70""</font></p>
<p align=""center""><font size=""5"">100% Polyester </font></p>
<p align=""center""><font size=""5"">Fully machine washable</font></p>

Comment: these are html codes which are included on description column with each cell in excel file and i want to insert it into db without any intruption. Thanks

Comment: These strings contain quotation marks... read my answer. The problem is that you are not escaping the strings in your SQL statement, or using MySQLi or PDO prepared strings

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that Description is simply a text string containing html markup, then you should escape it (or use prepared statements). This is because a string can contain quote characters, and is standard practise **whenever** using text strings in a database, nothing to do with PHPExcel.

Comment: Can you refer some php function which will do it. I have tried it to search on Google but i did't find satisfied thing yet. It will be very helpful for me if you refer some function thanks for your time.

Comment: Show me the PHP code that you are actually using to build and execute the insert statement

Comment: Hi Mark Baker, The problem has been resolved `$description = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(30, $row)->getValue();
  $item_description = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($description));` Thanks for your time.

Comment: Finally last thing tell in my excel file contain 248 rows When i execute query then it is inserting 247 rows. Second last row is missing what is the reason of it? Please read my above php codes and tell why one row is missing in the end. Im using loop like this: **for ($row=2; $row<=$highestRow; $row++) { some codes selected.... }**

Comment: I don't know, and very difficult to tell without seeing all of your code... do you have any "if" tests in your logic? Have you done any debugging to see the data being returned by each loop of the rows? Have you any exception handling in your database inserts? Are you sure that it should be inserting 248 rows... by my math if you start at row 2 you should be inserting 247

Comment: Actually my excel file has 249 including title heading. 248 means without first row. When i execute query then only 247 rows executed and skip one row which is 2nd last not first nor last just 2nd last. Iam wondering how it can be.

Comment: I don't know how it can be either, and without seeing more of your code so I can debug it for you it's very difficult to answer